# Is there a way to color different strands of curve hair without using multiple hair objects?

Tags: materials, bezier-curves, hair

I'm fairly new to doing hair using the new-(ish) curve hair system, And basically want to know if there are ways to, as I wrote, make a single hair system with different colors, to offer an elaboration I have some examples: In this picture of Reed Richards we see the back of his hair is white while the rest of his hair is brown, probably the easiest to just do multiple hair systems;
[image]

The next image is of Jason Todd from Gotham Knights, in which he has a white streak of hair running right through the rest of his hair, a far more difficult effect to replicate with multiple objects, since I'd have to match the grooming of one part with the other:
[image]

Does anyone know a way to make something like this work?

Comment: Thanks, that will work perfectly. In hindsight I cannot believe that It's that simple and I hadn't stumbled on a tutorial for it.

Comment: Great that it worked for you. I'm going to vote for this question to be marked as a duplicate.